# img não aparace usando thymeleaf, spring boot (com maven)

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

A imagem que eu quero adicionar está no seguinte diretório:

```
/src/main/resources/static/images/logo.png
```

E a tag no HTML está assim:

```
<img width="220px" height="70px" th:src="@{/static/images/logo.png}"/>
```

Entretanto, recebo a seguinte mensagem quando tento acessar a imagem:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). No message
>   available

Caso seja necessário saber, meu código do index:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Empresa | Simulado </title>
<link href="/static/images/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>

<body>
    <br />
    <h1 align="center">Teste</h1>
    <img height="70px" width="220px" src="/static/images/logo.png" />
```

**Ps: O favicon aparece normalmente**

Comment: A imagem `logo.png` encontra-se no diretório `static/images/` ?

Comment: Sim! O mais estranho é que se eu mudo o final do source para:

/static/images/favicon.ico 

A imagem aparece normalmente, seja na aba do navegador, seja no site mesmo.

Comment: Até cheguei a ver essa pergunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460618/inserting-an-image-from-local-directory-in-thymeleaf-spring-framework-with-mave

Mas continuo sem resolver o problema

Comment: Essa mensagem de erro que retorna é no `Console` do navegador ?

Comment: No console do navegador aparece: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução para o problema, como descrito no link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46877728/image-does-not-show-using-thymeleaf-and-spring/46877798#46877798

> Não é necessário a pasta `static` no caminho. Apenas é necessário o uso de @{/images/logo.png}, pois por padrão `src/main/resources/static/` é `/`